# Trying to create an all-day event using Google Calendar API v3 for Java causes an error

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I can create a timed event using the Java v3 Google Calendar API (as per the sample code on Google's website), but I need to create an all-day event.

I call the event's setStart() and setEnd(), i.e.

```
    event.setStart(startEventDateTime);
    event.setEnd(endEventDateTime);
```

These methods require and EventDateTime, i.e.

```
    EventDateTime startEventDateTime = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime);
    EventDateTime endEventDateTime = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime);
```

I use the setDateTime() methods as setDate() causes a 404 error.

setDateTime() requires a com.google.api.client.util.DateTime object, by doing

```
    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Passing in the TimeZone gives a time element so it's not an all day event.

I've tried setting dateOnly to true but this gives an error:

```
    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(true, startDate.getTime(), 0);
```

I can't get the other ways of creating DateTime to work:
Date date, TimeZone zone
long value
Date value
long value, Integer tzShift
String value

Which way do I create DateTime and can I use setDate(), i.e. new EventDateTime().setDate(...)?

Does anyone have a tested code snippet? Why isn't this documented by Google?

ps Interestingly, when reading events from Google, using getDate() causes an exception with timed events and getDateTime() an exception with all-day events. Need to use getDate() for all-day events and getDateTime() for timed events.

Answer (score 16):

Fixed.

To create an all-day event, you must use setDate() having created DateTime objects using a String (which I created by formatting my Date objects). The code:

```
    Date startDate = new Date(); // Or a date from the database
    Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 86400000); // An all-day event is 1 day (or 86400000 ms) long

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String startDateStr = dateFormat.format(startDate);
    String endDateStr = dateFormat.format(endDate);

    // Out of the 6 methods for creating a DateTime object with no time element, only the String version works
    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(startDateStr);
    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(endDateStr);

    // Must use the setDate() method for an all-day event (setDateTime() is used for timed events)
    EventDateTime startEventDateTime = new EventDateTime().setDate(startDateTime);
    EventDateTime endEventDateTime = new EventDateTime().setDate(endDateTime);

    event.setStart(startEventDateTime);
    event.setEnd(endEventDateTime);
```

Comment: The key trick here for me was the usage of the constructor [com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(String value)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime#DateTime(java.lang.String)) and specifying a string without time and offset (example: "2018-07-30")